# Search for a string from a variable and print only the 3 line above it

Tags: regex, powershell

I've a variable with output similar to this:

```
Volume 1
logical disk tag = 0x207e799987
Name = test
disk state = OFF
```

I may have 100 volumes but the variable returns only the disk with status "OFF".

```
$chk = "some command"
$off = "some command"
$offChk = $Chk | Select-String -Pattern $off -Context 1
```

I'm trying to push each 'failed / off' disk's 'logical disk tag' into another array.

Any hints on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using the `-Context` parameter but you have to change the value to `3,0` which means that you capture 3 lines above the match and zero below. Then you have to access the context:

```
(Select-String -Path 'yourFilePath' -Pattern 'disk state = OFF' -Context 3,0).Context.PreContext
```

Comment: Thanks very much Martin! tried '-Contect 3,0' before. 'Context.PreContext' helps! it prints the above 2 lines excluding the searched string. Looks good. I'm checking to see if I can print only the logical disk tag or atleast the whole line starts with 'logical disk tag'

Comment: You are welcome. Just add `-replace ('=.*')` to the line to get your output. Please consider to accepting the answer.

Comment: $diskTag = (($chk | Select-String -Pattern $off -Context 3,0).Context.PreContext -replace('=.*')))[1]

This command give an output 'logical disk tag'. Never used regex before. Could you please let me know the regex for printing the tag number instead? Thanks! :)

Comment: Just change the regex to `.*=\s+`

Comment: That helped! Thank you Martin!

Comment: In the original output, disk tag comes with a period at the end. Had to do '$diskTag=$diskTag.Substring(0,$diskTag.Length-1)'to remove the period.